# Unable to implement (1) tap & click on the same element and (2) swipe using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, swipe, tap

I'm writing tests in python/selenium to test a responsive website in chrome with Device mode enabled. There is a page with a flyer slide in the middle and a thumbnail container with images for all the pages in a flyer at the bottom. The flyer slide always shows the page that is selected from thumbnail container.

When the flyer page is first loaded, on mobile web, thumbnail container is displayed with a small Collapse button on the right; however, On device (emulated with user agent settings on Chrome), thumbnail container appears collapsed with an Expand button.

To scroll to different flyer pages on device there are 2 options:

Option 1. Open thumbnail bar & click flyer image of any page

STEPS: If I manually click the expand button, the thumbnail bar does get displayed. BUT, With selenium script, 
To open the thumbnail bar 2 events should be fired - 'tap' on the expand button should pop up the thumbnail bar and 'click' on the expand button should change change it to collapse button & also change the position of button over to the thumbnail bar.

Now the problem is 'tap' is provided in TouchActions and 'click' is provided in ActionChains & I do not know how to implement both the events in sequence on the same object. Can you help?

Here is what all I tried but nothing works:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
touch_actions = TouchActions(self._driver)  # or, self.browser
action_chain= ActionChains(self._driver)    # or, self.browser
el = self.wait_for_element_to_be_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, <expand button>)
touch_actions.tap(el).release(50,50)
action_chain.context_click(el).send_keys(Keys.LEFT).perform()  # works as right click
```

Also, Doing just self.click(element) converts the expand to collapse button & change its position without displaying the thumbnail bar.

Option 2: Swipe through the flyer slide:
To implement swipe on the flyer page to get to the different slide, I tried the 3 ways but it did not work too:

```
fs= self.wait_for_element_to_be_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, <flyer slide>)
touch_actions.flick_element(fs, 0, -100, 1).perform()

action_chain.click_and_hold(fs).move_to_element_with_offset(fs,-100,0).release().perform()

action_chain.click_and_hold(fs).move_by_offset(-100,0).perform()
```

Can someone please guide - what am I missing here & how can I implement both ways to get to the different flyer page? Thanks,